# Showing progressHUD when presenting a new viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am presenting a new ViewController through a storyboard. I am unsure of how do I show a progressHUD during the time it takes to present another ViewController.

**My current approach**

I am using SVProgressHUD and this is how I did it. The SVProgressHUD do not show up immediately when it is presenting another ViewController.

**Main problem with approach**

Progress bar is showing only at the end of the presentation of the ViewController instead of immediately.

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main",bundle: nil)
    var destViewController : UIViewController!
    switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:

        SVProgressHUD.show() // This shows the progress bar b
        destViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myViewController") as! UIViewController
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

To hide the progress view you can use the callback '-(void)prepareForSegue:sender:'. This method gets called on the view controller before a new view controller is about to be displayed.

Here is the API reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prepareForSegue:sender:

Comment: I tried displaying the progressHUD in that callback, however it is only showing the progressHUD after the viewcontroller has been presented. I want it to be shown immediately.

Comment: I am sorry, I meant you should use 'prepareForSegue:sender:' callback to hide the progress view, not to show it. You should show the progress view, whenever your business logic needs it - like when you know that current controller is no longer valid, just display the progress view and hide it in 'prepareForSegue:sender:'

Comment: the same problem still remains, the progress bar is only showing at the end of the presentation of the viewcontroller and not the start

Answer (score 1):

You can do it programmatically using

```
self.presentViewController(destViewController, animated: true) { () -> Void in
    // After presentation finishes.
    SVProgressHUD.dismiss() // dismiss HUD.
}
```

Comment: In the library ENSideMenu, it is using 
            self.setViewControllers([contentViewController], animated: true), so I am unable to use that function. Is there any workarounds?

Comment: You can try to use UINavigationControllerDelegate's callback method 
- navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:,be sure to set  self.navigationController?.delegate = self